# Typescript: Map Type to RawType, with fallback to Type

Tags: typescript

I have a collection of types. I want some of them to be mapped to a raw type, if it exists a rawtype for the specific Type. Otherwise should the Type itself be used.

I have tried:

```
type RawTypes = {
  MyTypeA: MyTypeARaw,
  // MyTypeB: Use MyTypeB
  MyTypeC: Partial<MyTypeC>,
  // MyTypeD: Use MyTypeD
  MyTypeE: DeepPartial<MyTypeE>,
  MyTypeF: Omit<MyTypeF, "extended">,
};

export type MappedType<T> = T extends keyof RawTypes ? RawTypes[T] : T;

// How I want to use it:
let a: MappedType<MyTypeA>;
```

This doesn't work, since the keys of RawTypes are strings.

```
// Using a string-literal makes mapped type work
let a: MappedType<"MyTypeA">;
// Using of type makes fallback-version work
let b: MappedType<MyTypeB>;
```

It is only for compile-time type-checking.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I went for a run, which cleared my mind, and I came up with this solution:

```
export type MappedType<T> =
  T extends MyTypeA ? MyTypeARaw :
  // MyTypeB: Use MyTypeB
  T extends MyTypeC ? Partial<MyTypeC> :
  // MyTypeD: Use MyTypeD
  T extends MyTypeE ? DeepPartial<MyTypeE> :
  T extends MyTypeF ? Omit<MyTypeF, "extended"> :
  T;
```

Now I can use them with:

```
let a: MappedType<MyTypeA>; // Will be MyTypeARaw
let b: MappedType<MyTypeB>; // Will be MyTypeB
```